# Record didn't delete when using javascript :(htmldb_delete_message,'DELETE');

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have problem which I click delete, and the delete action is processed.

but record is not getting deleted.

The Button I set the property Target to URL:

`javascript:apex.confirm(htmldb_delete_message,'DELETE');`

The PL/SQL Process:

```
begin

    delete from table_name
    where rowid=:p_row_id;

end;
```

Help me plz

Comment: Are you issuing a commit?

Comment: No need for commits in APEX. Would need to confirm value of whatever p_row_id is, and debug log output to trust the process actually ran.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
apex.confirm(htmldb_delete_message, 'DELETE')
```

the first parameter (htmldb_delete_message) represents text that will be displayed (by default, "Would you like to perform this delete action?").

The second parameter, DELETE, represents a **request**, so the PL/SQL process you wrote will *execute* if request has that name set. So, does it?

If it does, what remains is value of :P_ROW_ID item. Check whether its value is in session state. Doesn't matter that you see it on the screen - it must be in session state (that's usually done by submitting the page).

Finally, is there a row in the table whose ROWID is equal to :P_ROW_ID value?